Ubuntu 24.04 autoinstall.yaml will show Ready to install page
I am trying to do an offline automated installation of Ubuntu 24.04 desktop using a bootable USB. At the start, it will appear the "ready to install" page that will show "review your choices" that will show my list of configurations from my autoinstall.yaml then I will need to click install to continue the automated installation. Is there a way to bypass this page/setup? I tried to put interactive-sections: [] from what I googled but it does not work. I have checked my autoinstall.yaml and have all the required fields included.
